# Get flow run UUID in Prefect 2.0

Tags: python, prefect

I'm currently discovering Prefect and I'm trying to deploy it to schedule workflows. I struggle a bit to understand how to access some data though. Here is my problem: I create a deployment and run it via the Python API and I need the ID of the flow run it creates (to cancel it, may other things happen outside of the flow).

When I run without any scheduling I can access the data I need (the flow run UUID), but I kind of want the scheduling part. It may be because the `run_deployment` function is asynchronous but as I am nowhere near being an expert in Python I don't know for sure (well that, and the fact that my code never exits after calling the `main()` function).

Here is what my code looks like:

```
from prefect import flow, task
from prefect.deployments import Deployment, run_deployment
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timezone

# Import the flow:
from script import my_flow

# Configure the deployment:
deployment_name = "my_deployment"

# Create the deployment for the flow:
deployment = Deployment.build_from_flow(
    flow = my_flow,
    name = deployment_name, 
    version = 1, 
    work_queue_name = "my_queue",
)
deployment.apply()

def main():
    # Schedule a flow run based on the deployment:
    response = run_deployment(
        name = "my_flow/" + deployment_name,
        parameters = {my_param},
        scheduled_time = dateutil.parser.isoparse(scheduledDate),
        flow_run_name = "my_run",
    )
    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
exit()
```

I searched a bit and saw in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73524646/how-to-get-own-flow-run-id/73527611#73527611) that it was possible to print the flow run id as it was executed, but in my case I need **before** the execution.

Is there anyway to get that data (**using the Python API**)? Or to set the flow ID myself? (I've already thoroughly checked the docs, I'm quite sure this is not possible)

Thanks a lot for your time!

Gauthier

Answer (score 0):

As of [2.7.12](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/blob/main/RELEASE-NOTES.md#release-2712) - released the same day you posted your question - you can create names for flows programmatically. Does that get you what you need?

> Both tasks and flows now expose a mechanism for customizing the names of runs! This new keyword argument (`flow_run_name` for flows, `task_run_name` for tasks) accepts a string that will be used to create a run name for each run of the function. The most basic usage is as follows:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from prefect import flow, task

@task(task_run_name="custom-static-name")
def my_task(name):
  print(f"hi {name}")

@flow(flow_run_name="custom-but-fixed-name")
def my_flow(name: str, date: datetime):
  return my_task(name)

my_flow()
```

> This is great, but doesn’t help distinguish between multiple runs of the same task or flow. In order to make these names dynamic, you can template them using the parameter names of the task or flow function, using all of the basic rules of Python string formatting as follows:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from prefect import flow, task

@task(task_run_name="{name}")
def my_task(name):
  print(f"hi {name}")

@flow(flow_run_name="{name}-on-{date:%A}")
def my_flow(name: str, date: datetime):
  return my_task(name)

my_flow()
```

> See [the docs](https://docs.prefect.io/tutorials/flow-task-config/#basic-flow-configuration) or https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/pull/8378 for more details.

Alternatively, if you need the flow run id you can use `get_run_context().flow_run.id` in a flow or task.

API docs: https://docs.prefect.io/api-ref/prefect/context/?h=flow+run+context#prefect.context.get_run_context

Comment: Yes I considered this. But this doesn't solve the problem to get the ID of the flow, unfortunately. I'm pretty sure we can get it with Python API but as I am not comfortable with the async language, I took a shortcut and used the Prefect REST API instead. When you schedule a flow run via the latter, the response you get contains the generated flow run ID.

Comment: I updated my answer to add get_run_context().flow_run.id

Answer (score 0):

[`run_deployment`](https://docs.prefect.io/api-ref/prefect/deployments/#prefect.deployments.run_deployment%60) returns a flow run object - which you named `response` in your code.

If you want to get the ID before the flow run is actually executed, you just have to set `timeout=0`, so that `run_deployment` will return immediately after submission.

You only have to do:

```py
flow_run = run_deployment(
   name = "my_flow/" + deployment_name,
   parameters = {my_param},
   scheduled_time = dateutil.parser.isoparse(scheduledDate),
   flow_run_name = "my_run",
   timeout=0
)
print(flow_run.id)
```